# How to fix this CSS-based vertical menu with relative positioned second level?

Tags: css, submenu, css-position

I've got this simple CSS `ul li` menu with a second level to it, which should pop up below its parent and push down the rest.

Like this:

```
Option 1 <---- no positioning on UL
  Sub 1  <----- relative positioned UL
  Sub 2
Option 2
Option 3
```

For some reason, the relative positioned `UL` doesn't affect Option 2 as it should.

My try to put this in jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/hxQRt/

My HTML

```
<!-- SUBMENU  -->
<div id="" class="sidemeny_undersida"><ul class="menu"><li class="first current"><a href="miljorivning.aspx" title="Miljörivning" class="stylized">Miljörivning</a><ul>
<li><a href="rivning_av_vaggar_och_mattor.aspx">Rivning av väggar och mattor</a></li>
<li><a href="rivning_och_borttagning_av_golvbelaggning.aspx">Rivning och borttagning av golvbeläggning</a></li>
<li><a href="brokkar_med_bilningshammare.aspx">Brokkar med bilningshammare</a></li>
<li><a href="rivning_av_stora_byggnader.aspx">Rivning av stora byggnader</a></li>
</ul>
</li><li class=""><a href="miljosanering.aspx" title="Miljösanering" class="stylized">Miljösanering</a></li><li class=""><a href="haltagning121108.aspx" title="Håltagning" class="stylized">Håltagning</a></li><li class=""><a href="stambyten.aspx" title="Stambyten" class="stylized">Stambyten</a></li><li class=""><a href="golvslipning.aspx" title="Golvslipning" class="stylized">Golvslipning</a></li><li class="last "><a href="ventilationsrengoring121108.aspx" title="Ventilationsrengöring" class="stylized">Ventilationsrengöring</a></li></ul></div>
<!-- / SUBMENU  -->
```

My CSS

```
/* Level 1 */ 

.sidemeny_undersida,
.sidemeny_undersida li,
.sidemeny_undersida li a { margin: 0; padding: 0; float: none;  }

.sidemeny_undersida { display: block; width:200px; min-height:33px; margin: 20px 0 0 20px; float:left; }

.sidemeny_undersida li { display: block; width: 200px; padding: 4px 0 6px 0; margin: 0 0 5px 0; background: url(../images/sub_nav_bg.png) no-repeat bottom left; }

.sidemeny_undersida li a { color: #000; padding: 0 0 0 10px; }

.sidemeny_undersida li a:hover, 
.sidemeny_undersida li.current a  { color: #25a8de; }

.sidemeny_undersida li:last-child { background: none; }

/* Level 2 */

.sidemeny_undersida li.current ul { display: block; position: relative !important; width: 250px; min-height: 150px; margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0;   }

.sidemeny_undersida li li { width: inherit; height: 15px; margin-left: 10px; background: none; padding: 2px 0 0 0;  }

.sidemeny_undersida li li a,
.sidemeny_undersida li.current li a { font-size: 12px; color: #000; text-transform: none; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: Set it up on jsfiddle.net and you will get more people to help you.

Comment: Hi I've entered the html code aswell. All elements are generated dynamicly with .net code. An I just do the css etc.
Im also trying that jsfiddle site, tho Im new to this site so I really have no clue what im doing ;)

*Note* The HTML says "SUBMENU". Its generated as a submenu module but the "submenu" starts at level one instead of lvl 2.

Comment: Here is an appropriate jsFiddle URL: http://jsfiddle.net/FApA6/

Comment: I'm still not having any luck on this topic. I've gone through the code (all of it) several times but I cant find anything that would explain why all of a sudden the relative positioning wont work anymore. I've looked at several tutorials on this subject and they all say the same thing more or less.
I don't know if this http://jsfiddle.net/DANqg/ is better, I just tried to make a simple example of how its intended to work.
i still don't understand this tool fully.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add the second level `ul` tag. Your html should be as follows:

```
<ul>
<li>One
    <!-- This is the html tag you're missing -->
    <ul>
        <li>OneDotOne</li>
        <li>OneDotTwo</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Other than that your CSS is fine for basic functionality. Your basic example here: http://jsfiddle.net/DANqg/1/ 
And your initial menu example: http://jsfiddle.net/hxQRt/2/

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed that ul.
Basic functionality works, check. Yet this problem still persists. I eventually made a workaround with a absolute "floating" ul, but I still need this to work on a mobile version.
I've made this type of menu so many times and they've all worked fine. This just make no sense at all :(